# Write git diff to repository files

Tags: git, diff

I have a codebase that was partially generated automatically. Now, after a lot of modification, the code generator has a new version so if I regenerate the automatic part, a lot of the code will be overwritten. What I want to do, is to write the `git diff` patches to the files exactly as they are, so I can go over them and resolve the changes manually.

In other words, I want to apply patches, but keep both versions in files separated somehow (probably like a conflict), so I can find them in my IDE and decide what to keep or move around.

For example, say my HEAD state of file `a.c` is:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "main.h"

void someFunction(void) {
 Some setup
 not gonna change
 some random stuff 1
 closing remarks
}
```

Now, the file looks like this:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "main.h"

void someFunction(void) {
 different setup
 not gonna change
 // USER CODE BEGIN
 // USER CODE END
 closing remarks
}
```

What I want to see when I open the file in a text editor, is:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "main.h"

void someFunction(void) {
>> OLD
 Some setup
== NEW
 different setup
<<
 not gonna change
>> OLD
 some random stuff 1
== NEW
 // USER CODE BEGIN
 // USER CODE END
<<
 closing remarks
}
```

I tried checking out the changes in a new branch and merge to get conflicts and resolve them, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code generator then you can compare the changed files to your committed files with `git diff`. If you need a more interactive diff then you could use `git difftool` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)). The program git uses for `difftool` is configurable with `git config` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)); something like [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) should work.

Note that it's usually considered bad practice to commit generated files, you could consider committing only the files needed to generate the rest.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer, I'm well aware of `git diff` and `difftool`, and neither achieve what I expect, which is clearly shown in my question.